# Laravel collections mapWithKeys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-collection

I have been trying to create an array using laravel's collection function called [mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-mapwithkeys), but I couldn't achieve what I need.

Here is my code,

```
$years = range(1900, date('Y'));

return collect($years)->mapWithKeys(function($value){
    return [$value => $value];
})->all();
```

Expected result

```
Array
(
    [1900] => 1900
    [1901] => 1901
    [1902] => 1902
    ....
    [2017] => 2017
)
```

But what I get is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1900
    [1] => 1901
    [2] => 1902
    ...
    [117] => 2017
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested this code and it works perfectly:

```
$years = range(1900, date('Y'));
return collect($years)->map(function($i) {
    return ['year' => $i];
}, $years)->pluck('year', 'year');
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1900] => 1900
        )
) I'm getting values like this.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I'm wondering why it is not working with mapWithKeys function. If I replace [$value => $value] to something like ['s'.$value => $value] it works. I think the problem is with key and value being same.

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar under the hood `mapWithKeys()` uses `array_map()`, so it's just rebuilds given array. So you can't use this helper for building a plain array with desired structure.